# Is it possible to over-ride the x axis range in R package ggbio when using autoplot and ensdb transcripts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to use ggbio to plot gene transcripts.  I want to plot a very specific range so it matches my ggplot2 plots.  The problem is my example plot ends up having range of 133,567,500-133,570,000 regardless of the GRange and whether I specify xlim or not.

This example should only plot a small bit of intron (the thin arrowed line) but instead plots the full 2 exons and intron in between.  I believe autoplot wants to plot the entire transcript or transcripts present in the range and widens the range to accommodate for that.

```
  library(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)
  library(ggbio)
  ensdb <- EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86
  mut<-GRanges("10", IRanges(133568909, 133569095))
  gene <- autoplot(ensdb, which=mut, names.expr="gene_name",xlim=c(133568909,133569095))
  gene.gg <- gene@ggplot
  png("test_gene_plot_5.png")
    gene.gg
  dev.off()
```

Is there any way to over-ride this?   I've looked at the manual page for autoplot and I couldn't narrow down an option that would fix it.  Others have said to use xlim, but that does not seem to change anything

I like ggbio because it can make a ggplot2 object to be plotted along with other ggplot2 objects. I have not seen an example for that with other approaches like Gvis. But I would entertain other approaches if they could be combined with my existing plots.

Thanks!

Amy

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends wether you want clipped or squished data. Usually autoplot outputs a ggplot object at some point that can be manipulated as such.

For squished data:

```
library(GenomicRanges) # just to be sure start and end work
gene@ggplot + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(start(mut), end(mut)), oob = scales::squish)
```

[image]

For clipped data:

```
gene@ggplot + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(start(mut), end(mut)))
```

[image]

But to be totally honest, I'm unsure wether this is the most informative way to communicate that you are plotting the internals of an intron.

Alternatively, I've written a gene model geom at some point that doesn't work through the autoplot methods (which can sometimes be a pain if you want to customise everything). Downside is that you'd have to do some manual gene searching and setting aesthetics. Upside is that it works like most other geoms and is therefore easy to combine with some other data.

```
library(ggnomics) # from: https://github.com/teunbrand/ggnomics

# Finding a gene's exons manually
my_gene <- transcriptsByOverlaps(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86, mut)
my_gene <- exonsByOverlaps(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86, my_gene)
my_gene <- as.data.frame(my_gene)

some_other_data <- data.frame(
  x = seq(start(mut), end(mut), by = 10),
  y = cumsum(rnorm(19))
)

ggplot(some_other_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_genemodel(data = my_gene,
                 aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, 
                     y = max(some_other_data$y) + 1,
                     group = 1, strand = strand)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(start(mut), end(mut)))
```

[image]

Hope that helped!